# Routing between two networks

Tags: networking, routing, network-interface

I Have two devices connected over two different physical interfaces and two different bridges. How can I add a route between them in the router, so that I will be able to ping device 2 from device 1 and vice versa. Please find the diagram below.

```
        Device 1                      Router                   Device 2
+-----------------+     +----------------------------+    +-----------------+
|                 |     |                            |    |                 |
|           eth1  |     | br2                    br1 |    |  wlan0          |
|   169.254.10.10 |-----| 169.254.50.1      10.0.0.1 |----| 169.254.168.11  |
| (self assigned) |     |                            |    | (self assigned) |
+-----------------+     +----------------------------+    +-----------------+
```

Can I achieve this using route tables?

Answer (score 5):

Addresses in the [169.254.0.0/16](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3927) range are IPv4 link-local addresses, that is, addresses to be used only on the local network and not to be routed between network segments.

If you want to allow communication between `Device 1` and `Device 2` without having them on the same network segment, you should assign their network interfaces addresses from [private internet address space](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1918), such as `10.0.0.1` assigned to interface `br1` in your diagram.

Comment: Can I use proxy arp in this case?

Comment: Proxy arp may well work for what you need.  I avoid 169.254.0.0/16 as much as I can.

Comment: I cant touch devices 1 and 2. Is there anyway to make this working?

Comment: how to add route when using proxy arp?

Comment: He forgot to mention that he wants to [route multicast](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/400191/connecting-two-clients-on-different-physical-interfaces-using-smcroute/) in this setup (which won't work this way). Also, he's asking two questions about the same issue ...